# How can I make the elements on the header (links) to be the color I set, instead of blue?

Tags: html, css

I'm making a basic webpage to apply what I learnt of CSS. The theme of the web page is a video games guides site, and I made a header that is, basically, links to the main page, guides, forum to discuss videogamesd and a form to log in/sign up, and are going to be present on every page following this one. I want those links to be orange in contrast of the dark grey background of the page but, since they are links, they appear as blue, how do I fix this?

My code:
(ignore the text it is just to see that the font and styles apply correctly)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>ALEX GUIAS</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            body {font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
                background-color: #54545C;
                color:rgb(180, 220, 255)
                }
            header {
                color: rgb(255, 196, 0);
                text-align: center;
                padding: 20px 0;
                font-style: italic;
                font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
                font-weight: 700;
            }
            body h1 {color: #E70548;
                    font-family: Impact, Haettenschweiler, 'Arial Narrow Bold', sans-serif;
                    font-size: xx-large;
                    letter-spacing: 1.5px;
                }
            nav ul {list-style-type: none;
            }
            nav li {display: inline;
                    padding: 50px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="MainPage.html" target="blank">ALEXGUIAS</a></li>
                <li><a href="Guias.html" target="blank">GUÍAS</a></li>
                <li><a href="Foro.html" target="blank">FORO</a></li>
                <li><a href="Usuario.html" target="blank">REGISTRO O INICIO DE SESIÓN</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
        <h1>ufhuheyfghey</h1><br>
        fijiuegujujnedujngujierbubghbubiioujhioehiutgsyjrfshdg
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links_colors.asp

Comment: In short, you never set the style for the `a` elements' `color` property.

Comment: @HereticMonkey, yes, thenk you